# API call works on development, timesout on production heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, rest-client

I am using an API which works fine on development but timeouts when I call it from production or heroku run rails console.

I'm doing the following

```
url = "http://theapi.example.com"
response = RestClient.get url
```

Locally I get a 200 response, in proudction 
I get the following:

> RestClient::Exceptions::OpenTimeout: Timed out connecting to server
>   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.1/lib/restclient/request.rb:731:in
>   `rescue in transmit'  from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.1/lib/restclient/request.rb:647:in`
>   transmit'    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.1/lib/restclient/request.rb:145:in
>   `execute'     from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.1/lib/restclient/request.rb:52:in`
>   execute'     from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.1/lib/restclient.rb:67:in
>   `get'     from (irb):30   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in`
>   start'   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in
>   `start'   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in`
>   console'     from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in
>   `run_command!'    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in`
>   '    from script/rails:6:in `require'    from
>   script/rails:6:in`'

The API does not support ssl, not sure it is has anything to do with it.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout#timeout-behavior

Comment: Thanks @Bharatsoni but that is not the problem that I am having, it is something to do with production. The API is accessible, not overloaded and it returns 200 under a second in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API provider had Heroku's IP blocked to avoid attacks. He unblocked the IP of the request and everything worked.